# Formal Grammars : How can I apply recursion to use these terminal symbols as parenthesis

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, language-translation

Hi I have the following set of non-terminals : 
{A,B,C,X} , and terminals : {$,i,m,u}

The production rules I have done so far are :

1. X->A$
2. A->A B
3. A->B
4. B->i C u
5. C->m A
6. C->m C

In this example 'i,u' are supposed to act as brackets and so there has to be an equal balance on each side and at least one m in between.

```
I.e. Correct string : imu; iiimuuu; iimmmuiimuuimuu
                      ( )  ((( )))  ((   )(( ))( ))
```

What would I need to add in the production rules to be able to produce the desired derivations ? Thank you.

Comment: Haven't you akready done it?

Comment: @EJP - Hi. Thank you for the response. I have to an extent but at the moment i cant repeat the outside brackets as in the second and third examples ...